# List only directories names which match a pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I'm bit confused about the command or modifiers to obtain:
List of directories (only directories, not including subdirectories) which names include a pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A regular expression-style pattern? A glob-style pattern? Should this list be formatted to be unambiguously read by other tools (`printf %s\0'`, with a reader expecting NUL-delimited input)? Formatted for human consumption (`ls`)? Formatted some other way?

Comment: The final commando erasing directories date, size and perm is: ls -l | grep '^d' | grep 'Castellano' | cut -c61-

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Wrong place for your comment or wrong user ?

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez Please read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs to understand why this practice is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's works for me.

But it outputs also the directory characteristics, permissions, date, etc. and I want to display only the directory name.

```
ls -t | grep '^d' | grep 'pattern'
```

Comment: If you want only the names, that adds no advantage over `printf '%s\n' */` (`*/`, unlike `*`, expands only to directories) -- but is far slower and potentially buggy.

Answer (score 73):

You are probably after the `-d` switch of `ls`:

```
ls -d *pattern*/
ls --directory *pattern*/
```

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez: I guess this is "a"

Answer (score 8):

Use this little hack:

```
printf '%s\n' *pattern*/
```

if you prefer all on the same line :

```
echo *pattern*/
```

or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) array :

```
arr=( *pattern*/ )
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]%/}"
```